# Is there a way to store in a variable the text in a certain element in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, automated-tests

I have a selenium script that I created with Selenium IDE. I was
wondering if there is anyway to store the text that is in a certain
element in a variable so that I can use that text later in the script? I am using selenium IDE to do it and then importing it into browsermob.

For Example: I have this html:

```
<div id=title>
     <h2>Website</h2>
     <h3><span>web app</span>www.google.com</h3>
</div>
```

The text in the h3 (www.google.com) changes with different pages. I want a script to be able to run on all these pages that grabs the text in the h3 (in this case www.google.com), and stores it in a javascript variable which I can use in a later part of the script.

Comment: @chromedude: if what you want is to use some selected node within other XPath expression, this can be done with XPath only. You should provide document sample, and  expression could be became... verbose, of course. If you want to declare a variable with Selenium, then this is not an XPath question.

Comment: @Alejandro I think that is what I want to do, I want to declare a variable that will hold the text that is in a certain element. How would you do that then?

Comment: @Alejandro hmm... I guess I don't completely understand what you are saying. I just added an update to my question. Is that what your talking about?

Comment: @chromedude: Now your question is clear. You want to declare a variable in script context, not XPath expression context.

Comment: @Alejandro yes, that sounds right. so... how do you do it?

Comment: @chromedude: I'm not an Selenium expert, that's why I'm not answering. But from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#store-commands-and-selenium-variables) it looks like you need `storedVars['name']` to use stored variable in Selenium commands' target and value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you store an elements text with selenium in a javascript variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740281/how-do-you-store-an-elements-text-with-selenium-in-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [How do you store an elements text with selenium in a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740281/how-do-you-store-an-elements-text-with-selenium-in-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 3):

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#store-commands-and-selenium-variables

Depending what exactly you are trying to do, the storeEval command may be of use.  You should just be able to start the Xpath with // as the argument to the storeEval command (so that Selenium knows that you are referencing an Xpath rather than, say, a DOM element).

Comment: how would you refrence the variable in the ${} after it is created? I want to grab the text in a certain area of the page and then later on in the script type that text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code for your task. It will work.

```
storeEval window.document.getElementById('menuless') varname 
echo varname
```