# How do you store an elements text with selenium in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have this html:

```
<div class="title">
<div class="subtitle">
<div id="flhcd1>
<h3>Hello</h3>
<span></span>
</div>
<div class="subtitle2">
</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to use selenium and javascript to store the text in the `<h3>` (Hello) in the variable `titleText` .

I will be using this code in browsermob for monitoring tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BrowserMob you can do

```
var titleText = selenium.getText("//div[@id='flhcd']/h3");
```

and then use titleText like you would any variable.